# Silverlight out of browser WebBrowser block

Tags: silverlight, browser

I've created a silverlight 4.0 OOB application. Inside a menu of the application I've a WebBrowser where I load some predefined webPages. The issue is that those Pages have some links that open a new Internet Explorer instance. I would like to prevent openning that new window, because my application should be the only one running in the computer. I can´t find any event that could give me the information of my app loosing the focus. I don´t know if I can also capture this in the webBrowser.

thanks for the repply!!

UPDATE:

I've found a workaround, In my case I'm sure that the default browser is Internet Explorer, so changing Internet options the problem dissapears. In Internet Options / Privacy / PopUp blocker / Settings, I've set the blocking level to "High" and have unchecked the "show notification bar" checkbox.

Comment: I afraid you're out of luck with WebBrowser control, since it doesn't provide any event then user clicks on the link or any way to cancel navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some of the links in the webpage have a target="_blank" set on them.

Comment: I suppose it, but as it´s a commercial webpage I cannot change the target.